# Python sending email script not getting credentials from external file

Tags: python, email, authentication

```
import smtplib
import os
import time 


def send_email(contacts):
    try:
        user= passw=""
        with open("credentials.txt", "r") as f:
            file = f.readlines()
            user = file[0].strip()
            passw = file[1].strip()
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls() # it is necessary to start this before login
        server.login(user, passw) # login credentials

        subject = "Assignment Task for Working student job"
        msg = "This is a msg body of assignment.  "
        message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, msg)

        for i in contacts:
            server.sendmail(user, contacts, message)
            print(f"successfully sent email to {i} and wait for 10 seconds" )
            time.sleep(10)

        server.quit()

        print("Success: Email sent!")

    except:
        print("Email failed to send.")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    #sender, password = read_creds()

    contacts = ['editorawais@gmail.com', 'editorawais@yahoo.com', 'editorawais@live.com','techwpblog@gmail.com']
    send_email(contacts)
```

I created this email script. But now i am getting error on login. My credentials.txt is just of two lines.

```
"Email address"
"Password"
```

Please can anybody help me where i am missing something. And the correct way possibly. Thanks

Comment: Does the file really have quotes in it? It shouldn't.

Comment: Are you certain that the problem is that it's not getting the credentials? Your try-except block catches all errors, not just ones specific to the password-fetching.

Comment: @HampusLarsson Bro i am getting only except block print .

Comment: @Barmar Okay let me try

Comment: @Barmar still it's not accepting credentials...

Comment: @awais And how do you know that the except block is printing is because of credentials? Why don't you print the actual error that was raised so you know the reason?

Comment: @Barmar sorry i will post the actual error Bro.

Comment: @Barmar i am getting this error.
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials o13sm3722715ejb.46 - gsmtp')

Comment: Does `print(user, passw)` show what you expect?

Comment: @Barmar after printing print(user) it gives me this result... user = 'awaisbtu@gmail.com'

Comment: You shouldn't have `user =` in the file. It should just contain the username and password, not an assignment statement.

Comment: Are you sure the username is supposed to be `awaisbtu@gmail.com` and not just `awaisbtu`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes Sir exactly i want this...

Comment: @Barmer Ok Bro let me remove this assignment statement and will directly use.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the quotation marks if you indeed have those in the txt file. Python will try to plug in everything on the first and second line including the "" try just doing this in your .txt file.

email
password